# How is this contract simulating write functions of another contract and getting new state values on the mainnet?

Tags: solidity, web3js, web3.py, evm, pancakeswap

Contract: [0xdEdf20172b6dC39817026c125f52d4fad8E0f29b](https://bscscan.com/address/0xdEdf20172b6dC39817026c125f52d4fad8E0f29b)

ABI: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Trading-Tiger/Pancakeswap_BSC_Sniper_Bot/main/abis/BSC_Swapper.json

Sample code: (https://github.com/Trading-Tiger/Pancakeswap_BSC_Sniper_Bot/blob/main/txns.py)

```
tokenInfos = self.swapper.functions.getTokenInformations(self.token_address).call()
buy_tax = round((tokenInfos[0] - tokenInfos[1]) / tokenInfos[0] * 100 ,2) 
sell_tax = round((tokenInfos[2] - tokenInfos[3]) / tokenInfos[2] * 100 ,2)
```

The structure of `tokenInfos` from the ABI:

```
output[0] = BuyEstimateOutput (probably using getAmountsOut from pancakeswap router)    
output[1] = BuyRealOutput    
output[2] = SellEstimateOutput    
output[3] = SellRealOutput
```

I ran `getTokenInformations()` to check if it actually works:

```
contract = '0xdEdf20172b6dC39817026c125f52d4fad8E0f29b'
token = '0x2A9718defF471f3Bb91FA0ECEAB14154F150a385' # random token taken from bscscan

contract = w.eth.contract(address=contract, abi=abi)

data = contract.functions.getTokenInformations(token).call()
print (data)
```

OUTPUT:

`[132208265708940319, 118987440043519338, 8879124915279981, 7991215663722533, True, True, True]`

There wasn't any state changing transactions on bscscan after running the code: https://bscscan.com/address/0xdEdf20172b6dC39817026c125f52d4fad8E0f29b.

`getTokenInformations()` must be simulating the buy and sell functions.

So, this unverified contract is simulating pancakeswap (or uniswap) contract's state changing write functions and get the new state values.

How is that possible?